# How can I scroll an element when page body scrolls?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I have a fixed side nav with a long list of jump links. When the user scrolls the main page content the jump links get highlighted to show where the user is in the list.

The problem is the fixed side nav has overflow-y:scroll; and this does not actually scroll up or down when the links get highlighted.

https://jsfiddle.net/nz6b7cj9/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div style="float:left">
    <div id="fixed-side-nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="link1" class="link1">Jump links</a></li>
        <li><a href="link2" class="link2">Jump links</a></li>
        <li><a href="link3" class="link3">Jump links</a></li>
        <li><a href="link4" class="link4">Jump links</a></li>
        <li><a href="link5" class="link5">Jump links</a></li>
        <li><a href="link6" class="link6">Jump links</a></li>
        <li><a href="link7" class="link7">Jump links</a></li>
        <li><a href="link8" class="link8">Jump links</a></li>
        <li><a href="link9" class="link9">Jump links</a></li>
        <li><a href="link10" class="link10">Jump links</a></li>
        <li><a href="link11" class="link11">Jump links</a></li>
        <li><a href="link12" class="link12">Jump links</a></li>
        <li><a href="link13" class="link13">Jump links</a></li>
        <li><a href="link14" class="link14">Jump links</a></li>
        <li><a href="link15" class="link15">Jump links</a></li>
        <li><a href="link16" class="link16">Jump links</a></li>
        <li><a href="link17" class="link17">Jump links</a></li>
        <li><a href="link18" class="link18">Jump links</a></li>
        <li><a href="link19" class="link19">Jump links</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="content" style="float:left">
    <h2 id="link1">
     HERE
    </h2>
    <p>Content here</p>
    <h2 id="link2">
     HERE
    </h2>    
    <p>Content here</p>
    <h2 id="link3">
     HERE
    </h2>        
    <p>Content here</p>
    <p>Content here</p>
    <p>Content here</p>
    <p>Content here</p>
    <h2 id="link4">
     HERE
    </h2>    
    <p>Content here</p>
    <h2 id="link5">
     HERE
    </h2>    
    <p>Content here</p>
    <h2 id="link5">
     HERE
    </h2>    
    <p>Content here</p>
    <h2 id="link6">
     HERE
    </h2>    
    <p>Content here</p>
<h2 id="link7">
 HERE
</h2> 
    <p>Content here</p>
<h2 id="link8">
 HERE
</h2> 
    <p>Content here</p>
<h2 id="link9">
 HERE
</h2> 
    <p>Content here</p>
<h2 id="link10">
 HERE
</h2> 
    <p>Content here</p>
<h2 id="link11">
 HERE
</h2> 
    <p>Content here</p>
<h2 id="link12">
 HERE
</h2> 
    <p>Content here</p>
<h2 id="link13">
 HERE
</h2> 
    <p>Content here</p>
<h2 id="link14">
 HERE
</h2> 
    <p>Content here</p>
<h2 id="link15">
 HERE
</h2> 
    <p>Content here</p>
<h2 id="link16">
 HERE
</h2> 
    <p>Content here</p>
<h2 id="link17">
 HERE
</h2> 
    <p>Content here</p>
<h2 id="link18">
 HERE
</h2> 
    <p>Content here</p>
<h2 id="link19">
 HERE
</h2> 
    <p>Content here</p>
    <p>Content here</p>
    <p>Content here</p>
    <p>Content here</p>
    <p>Content here</p>
    <p>Content here</p>
    <p>Content here</p>
    <p>Content here</p>
    <p>Content here</p>
    <p>Content here</p>
    <p>Content here</p>
    <p>Content here</p>
    <p>Content here</p>    
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  position: relative;
}

#fixed-side-nav{
  border:1px solid #ededed;
    padding:10px;
    width:12%;
    background-color:#fff;
    bottom:20px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    bottom:20px;
    position:fixed;
  top:90px;
}
#content{
  float:left;
  margin-left:200px;
  background-color:white;
  width:100%;
}

#fixed-side-nav li.active {background-color:yellow}
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(window).on('load scroll resize', function (){

    // Assign active class to nav links while scrolling
    var windowTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    jQuery('h2').each(function (index, elem) {
        var offsetTop = jQuery(elem).offset().top;
        var outerHeight = jQuery(this).outerHeight(true);

        if( windowTop > (offsetTop - 110) && windowTop < ( offsetTop + outerHeight)) {
            var elemId = jQuery(elem).attr('id');
            jQuery('#fixed-side-nav li.active').removeClass('active');
            jQuery('#fixed-side-nav a.'+elemId).parents('li').addClass('active');
        }
    }); 
});
```

Is there a way I can scroll the fixed side nav to show the highlighted link? I want to do this without using focus() because this isnt good for accessibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Element.scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView):

```js
jQuery('#fixed-side-nav a.'+elemId).parents('li')[0].scrollIntoView(false);
```

(Notice we're using `[0]` to get the element from the jQuery object)

This function also has some animation options you can use, read in the linked docs.